# C Splitting Strings

Tags: c, string, split, strtok, string-literals

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char *strArray[40];

void parsing(char *string){
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(string, " ");
  while(token != NULL)
  {
    strcpy(strArray[i], token);
    printf("[%s]\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
char *command = "This is my best day ever";
parsing(command); //SPLIT WITH " " put them in an array - etc array[0] = This , array[3] = best

return 0;
}
```

Here it is my code, is there any simply way to solve it? By the way my code is not working. Im new at coding C language and i dont know how can i handle it :( Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strArray[40];

void parsing(const char *string){//Original does not change
    int i = 0;
    strArray[i++] = strdup(string);//make copy to strArray[0]

    char *token = strtok(*strArray, " ");
    while(token != NULL && i < 40 - 1){
        strArray[i++] = token;
        //printf("[%s]\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    strArray[i] = NULL;//Sentinel

}

int main(void){
    char *command = "This is my best day ever";
    parsing(command);

    int i = 1;
    while(strArray[i]){
        printf("%s\n", strArray[i++]);
    }
    free(strArray[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
int parsing(char *string){//can be changed
    int i = 0;

    char *token = strtok(string, " ");
    while(token != NULL && i < 40){
        strArray[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);//Ensure a memory for storing
        strcpy(strArray[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    return i;//return number of elements
}

int main(void){
    char command[] = "This is my best day ever";
    int n = parsing(command);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", strArray[i]);
        free(strArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest, when i try to reach second object of this array it says NULL. For example when i type printf(%s, strArray[1]), it returns null. Why this happens?

Comment: @Berkin Detail is unknown.
Please indicate the specific examples that can be reproduced.

Comment: Here it is my Code. https://github.com/berkin768/CSplit.git . When i wrote [1] , it returns null. I dont know Why. Many thanks :)

Comment: @Berkin `scanf("%s",command);`  : `%s` does not accept white-spaces.(so `command` has  one word string) So Change to `scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", command);` or `fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);...`... = strtok(XXXXX, " \n");`

Comment: YEEAAH IT WORKS, SO MANY THANKS I LOVE STACK OVERFLOW <3

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` actually modify the supplied argument hence you cannot  pass a string literal and expect it to work.

You need to have a modifiable argument to get this working.

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

FWIW, any attempt to modify a string literal invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with your helps, thank you all :)

Its my split library = https://goo.gl/27Ex6O

Codes are not dynamic, if you enters 100 digit input, it will crash i guess

we can use the library with these argument :

**parsing (outputfile,inputfile,splitcharacter)**

THANKS